Is Produce Flame a spell that the caster casts upon themself?
The spell block for Produce Flame does not list a target, yet the text says:

Flames as bright as a torch appear in your open hand. The flames harm neither you nor your equipment.
In addition to providing illumination, the flames can be hurled or used to touch enemies...

So the flames appear in your hand, produce light, and you can attack with them.  So, is this a spell that you cast on yourself?
The motivation for this question comes from the Druid's Share Spells ability:

Share Spells (Ex): At the druid's option, she may have any spell ... she casts upon herself also affect her animal companion...

I am interested in whether a Druid can share Produce Flame with her companion -- perhaps presuming that the companion has hands (and can perhaps make melee or ranged attacks).

Side question related to this- could the producer be able to produce and/or keep a flame without hands?

No
Produce flame isn't a targeted spell nor a personal one, instead it's an effect spell:

Range: 0 ft.
Effect: Flame in your palm

The distinction is minor in most cases, but relevant in this one. What the spell does is create an effect (a flame in your palm) at a range of 0 feet (within your square) and give you the ability to do something with it (the description of the spell).
The distinction is clarified in the Aiming a Spell section of the Magic chapter, beginning on page 175 of the Player's Handbook.
